# Multi-Tenant shared Users Tables: Need an advice

Tags: postgresql, multi-tenant

Am writing multiple Multi-Tenant applications with separate database per each application (I've decided to go with shared database different schema approach). Each application have Staffs Table for tenants' staffs and Customers for, well customers.

The problem am having is all my applications share the two tables and so there are going to be duplicates if each database is going to be completely independent.

I have thought of having a common database with Staffs and Customers table and have a different app (like Oauth2 server) handling the registration and login. And then have stub table Users in each multi-tenant apps with columns `id` and `role`(customer/staff) forming Primary key and gets their data from remote Staffs and Customers respectively.

Am not sure this is a good approach so and if there are better ways to handle that.

If am not clear let me know in comments.

Comment: Your approach seems fine. Only one application can write (preferable, only one application can read) to a table / schema. You may also check party - party role pattern.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Do you have any recommended reading on party-party role pattern? Google comes with a lot of results sometimes and its hard to sift with little time I have.

Comment: found this very helpful link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969133/database-design-articles-blog-posts-photos-stories/4970646#4970646

Comment: I can't provide a specific link. I am using telco specific [documentations](https://www.tmforum.org/resources/suite/gb922-information-framework-sid-r17-0-0/) and its members only. The Idea is; individual, customer, organization are different relations. An individual accesses to a system via his "individual-identification" (e-mail/ password or a key card) after that can do anything according to the roles. he can be a customer and at the same time a manager of a supplier company.its not a software design patter but a business model pattern. You need to design the code according to the needs.

Comment: After a lot of searching and sifting I finally found a youtube video that gave me a good foundation and now I unsertand what you mean.

If you get time to put your comments together as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Thank you for your time

Comment: Can you share that video link so that other readers could benefit it. You can also write answer of this question yourself. I think its better and more detailed with your research done.

Comment: Ok I will do. I just didn't wanted to take credit for your idea which propelled me to the right direction. Video is here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UCvAa5wh5lg

Comment: I posted it, if you or anyone can improve it, I will appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is the approach I came up with. Store All user information and details to the Oauth2 Server/Login API and use it to login. Then in each of the service tables just store user ID, role picked up from login into Oauth2 server/Login API and save them into "users" table of your a specific service. That way you can preserve service data integrity while preventing duplicates.

As to Oauth2/Login service, you can use Party-Roles model (also known as Super-Type/Sub-Type). This video well illustrates it but in case you cannot watch it, just make People table and then Customers and Staffs table relating with People table with 1-to-1 relationship with a type.

Thanks to @Sahap Asci for pointing that out in the comment.